# How to apply a css class on a MVC Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I have the following tag in my MVC Application. How can I apply a class to my textbox?

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username", "", new { maxlength = 50 })%>
```

Comment: You have what appears to be a correct answer - accept it?

Answer (score 10):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username", "", new { maxlength = 50, @class = 'your-classname' })%>
```

Then in your CSS file you would use this selector:

```
.your-classname { ...css rules here... }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the class name of the input box is "username" then use:

```
input[type=text].username {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I believe the Html.TextBox helper method will also automatically create an id from the name field:

```
id="username"
```

You could then access the text box via CSS with:

```
#username {
    /* styles */
}
```